# Prevent .php extension in htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

One of my clients' sites has been hit by a mass amount of toxic links to "van.php" after there web url.

What I am looking to do is redirect anything with the extension of .php to an 404 page.

e.g

- domain.com/index.php
- domain.com/van.php
- domain.com/anything.php

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```